# Base64 string conversion to byte array not working properly

Tags: java, html, arrays, image, base64

I'm trying to convert Base64 string into byte array using org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

```
byte[] image = Base64.decodeBase64("Base64 String");
```

and then converting byte array to Base64 like

```
String Base64String = Base64.encodeBase64String(image);
```

but the base64String is different from the original base64 string. I dont get it where I went wrong

Comment: Different in  what way? Can you give a specific input, the output you expect and the output you get instead?

Comment: In what way is it different? Does it have anything to do with the [NOTE:](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64String(byte[])) in the Javadoc?

Comment: Different how? Can you show us a *small* example?

Comment: I have an image converted into base64 format. I'm converting the base64 string image into byte array and storing it in mysql database. When i'm trying to convert the byte array into base 64 string the html image shows file is broken, when i debug i saw that the input bse64 string and output base64 are not same

Comment: Use proper encoding like "UTF-8" while encoding and decoding the byte array

Comment: The example given in the question will not work because your Base64 string contains a space which could not occur in a real Base64 string and commons codec seems to just ignore it

Answer (score -1):

Use encodeBase64 not encodeBase64String.